# download custom option uploaded image in order even if Add Store Code to Urls set yes

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, sales-order

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

In my Store Under System -> Configuration -> General -> Web , I set **Add Store Code to Urls** Yes.

Due to i get problem to download custom option image from order. If I set NO than i able to download image but I don't want to disable this option .
its may be generate problem for past seo work which has done.

Is any way to get download custom option image from order ?